# How to use VBA `onChange` to mirror any cell value changes to a second master sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file with two sheets (`A` and `B`). I am trying to automatically mirror any changes made to Sheet `A` to a different range in Sheet `B`:

## Sheet `A`:

- Each row contains either an activity for a particular project or an summary row for a project. I only need to deal with the summary rows (project is specified in column 1)
- There are three consecutive columns for each month (Predicted/Misc/Actual) that are in columns (columns 12-47)
- The changes will only be getting made to the 'third' columsn (ie Jan=14, Feb=17 ...Dec=47)

## Sheet `B` (master sheet):

- This is the master file that contains summary information (one row per project)
- Contains just one column for each month (columns 38-49)

My attempt so far is below using `Worksheet_Change` but I can't get it to work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal SourceA As Range)
    Dim TargetB As Range
    Dim SheetACalendar As Range
    Dim SheetBCalendar As Range
    Dim project As String

    With ThisWorkbook
      Set SheetACalendar = .Sheets("SheetA").Range(Cells(1, 12), Cells(1, 47)) 'Jan=14 thru Dec=47
      Set SheetBCalendar = .Sheets("SheetB").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 49)) 'Jan=38 thru Dec=49
    End With
    
    'Only Update SheetB if the changed cell (SourceA) is a summary row
    'Identify the project, lookup on sheetB and update the correct months value to match the change in SheetA
    If Cells(SourceA.Row, 3) = "Total" And (SourceA.Column = 14 Or SourceA.Column = 17 Or SourceA.Column = 20 Or SourceA.Column = 23 Or SourceA.Column = 26 Or SourceA.Column = 29 Or SourceA.Column = 32 Or SourceA.Column = 35 Or SourceA.Column = 38 Or SourceA.Column = 41 Or SourceA.Column = 44 Or SourceA.Column = 47) Then
        project = Cells(SourceA.Row, 1).Value
        TargetB = Range(SheetBCalendar).Find(project, Cells(1, 1), SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
        TargetB.Item(1, SourceA.Column) = SourceA.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Explain " but I can't get it to work" - error on what line? Result that happens?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I'm having problems working out the issues but at the moment with code in the question,  debug says that subscript is out of range for `Set SheetACalendar` line

Comment: I believe that's the wrong syntax - if you're going to hardcode the cell range - instead of `Cells(1, 12), Cells(1, 47)` use `"<col><row>:<endcol><endrow>"` and do the same on row below. Update your code in question with edits and errors

Comment: First double check the names of the sheets that they are exactly the same and do not have unprintable characters that are missing in the vba reference.  Second you need to apply the same sheet parentage to the `Cells()` inside the `Range()`  Or it will try to use Cells from the active sheet in the range on a different sheet and it will throw an error if they are not the same. see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949470/vba-error-1004-when-trying-to-pull-values-from-a-worksheet/37950200#37950200

Comment: The issue seems to be related to the sheets: if I start the macro running with the active cell on `SheetA` then I get the "Application-defined or object-defined" error when it tries to `set SheetBCalendar`. However, if I select a cell on `SheetB` before running the amcro then I get the same error for the `Set sourceA` line

Comment: If I active each sheet in turn with `.Worksheets("SheetB").Activate` then this step works - although surely I don't need to change the activesheet for this??

Comment: Then it is to the second point in my last comment, you need to assign the proper parentage to each of the `Cells()` inside the range.